# How to condense not conditions in AWS CloudSearch structured query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Is it possible to simplify the following structured query with AWS CloudSearch (2013 API):

```
(and (not sc:1) (not sc:4) (not sc:9) (not sc:13) (not sc:14) 'one' 'two')
```

so that the `not` conditions are merged somehow?
I can't use `range` because my values are not sequential, unless I've misunderstood how that works. I've got a good few more values to check than in that example, so the end result is a bit ugly.

The docs don't seem to mention anything but single value and range regarding [searching numbers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-numbers.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [De Morgan's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra), you can rewrite

`(and (not sc:1) (not sc:4) (not sc:9) (not sc:13) (not sc:14))`

as

`(not (or sc:1 sc:4 sc:9 sc:13 sc:14))`

Which I think is not exactly what you were hoping for since it repeats the `sc:` term but is a bit simpler